# Exception when registering the JMX bean MessageHistory from Spring Integration into a Spring XD Module

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

If I try to use the Message History bean from Spring Integration "int:message-history" when developing a Spring XD module, it fails when try to export the JMX bean.

I've seen that the naming strategy used is org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.jmx.ModuleObjectNamingStrategy

I already open a ticket for that https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3748

Is there any workaround for that? Like explicitly use another MBeanExporter and add a different name for the bean?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the `ModuleObjectNamingStrategy`; I'll see if I can come up with a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gary, for now I have implemented other class like the ModuleObjectNamingStrategy and changed the mbean-exporters.xml to use that one if the bean is the  messageHistoryConfigurer I create the ObjectName instance like:

```
String name = domain +":name=messageHistoryConfigurer";
ObjectName originalName = new ObjectName(name);
```

Comment: Yup; that's what I was going to suggest. Are you aware that XD has a higher-level (module) history tracking feature? See [Deployment Manifest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#deployment-manifest).

Comment: Yes, but I try to measure the latency and thread management inside each module, and also overall the whole stream, I need to know where the bottlenecks are and so on. With Spring XD I can only have this at the stream level, I need also to go deep at the module level.